# Visual Studio configuration for database access

Tags: mysql, visual-studio

I have the following in my initialization routine to connect to a database.

```
        String server = "localhost";
        String database = "jeniferdb";
        String uid = "poalogin";
        String password = "oracle";
        string connectionString;
        connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" + database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";

        connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        CloseConnection();
```

Can this be put into the Visual studio Configuration file so that I can change the executable from test to prod by only changing a config file.
I once remember (but forgot) in another visual product this could be put in a VS file so changing the database to access was simple changing the xml file.

or what is the best method to secure the connection string.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you put this values in a configuration file like **appsettings.json** or **web.config** and read from it. And also you can have a build variant like Debug and Release for the debugging and release version of your product.

**NOTE:** if you put the configuration in separate file it helps a lot after deploying your product because no need to open the source code and deploy it again you can actually change the value in the configuration file. and also this will helps in development.

[this tutorial show how to read values from configuration file](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1173468/Four-Ways-to-Read-Configuration-Setting-in-Csharp)